# Trouble transforming a string into an array with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have some trouble transforming a string into an array. The separators between numbers are spaces, and the thousands also.

My string is this:

```
'25 127,4 17 588,6 16 264,3 324,4 8,7'
```

I want it to look like this:

```
['25 127,4', '17 588,6', '16 264,3', '324,4', '8,7']
```

or better like this:

```
['25127,4', '17588,6', '16264,3', '324,4', '8,7']
```

I was trying to use *regex* and *findall* to do so, but the problem is that it only captures 5-digit numbers.

My code is kind of like this:

```
a = '25 127,4 17 588,6 16 264,3 324,4 8,7'
print(re.findall(r'\d+\s\d+,\d{1}', a))
```

which gives me this output:

```
['25 127,4', '17 588,6', '16 264,3', '4 8,7']
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Try [`(?! )[\d ]+,\d`](https://regex101.com/r/sKKlsc/1/)

Comment: Maybe `re.findall(r'[0-9\s]+,\d+', s)` given a string `s`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @HaoWu and Mark. It worked!!

Answer (score 1):

The regex recommendation in the comment seems to work for your example, but having spaces represent delimiters and thousand separators in your data will cause a lot of problems. If possible you should see if a different sort of delimiter could be used!

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations. Sure will change the delimeter

Answer (score 1):

You can optionally repeat matching a space and matching 1+ digits. (Note that `\s` can also match a newline)

Then remove the spaces from the matches.

```
\b\d+(?: \d+)*,\d\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/it6ALa/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"\b\d+(?: \d+)*,\d\b"
s = "25 127,4 17 588,6 16 264,3 324,4 8,7"
result = [m.replace(" ", "") for m in re.findall(pattern, s)]
print(result)
```

Output

```
['25127,4', '17588,6', '16264,3', '324,4', '8,7']
```